# Google Script: Adding UI Menu always results in "Read data" menu item

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I'm trying to use [this API example code](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#addMenu%28String,Object%29) for the `AddMenu` function.

But every time I refresh my spreadsheet, I just get a menu called `Script Center Menu` with a single item `Read Data`.

What on earth is going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 onOpen functions in your script... see below :

One at the top of your script :

```
 function onOpen() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
   var menuEntries = [];
   // When the user clicks on "addMenuExample" then "Menu Entry 1", the function function1 is
   // executed.
   menuEntries.push({name: "Menu Entry 1", functionName: "function1"});
   menuEntries.push(null); // line separator
   menuEntries.push({name: "Menu Entry 2", functionName: "function2"});

   ss.addMenu("addMenuExample", menuEntries);
 }
```

And at the very end of your script file :

```
function onOpen() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Read Data",
    functionName : "readRows"
  }];
  spreadsheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

I used a search on "script center" to check that. (command F on Mac)

Comment: Argh! How embarrassing. Thanks so much for spotting it. Perhaps I should delete the question as too localized?

Comment: as you want but you're probably not the first (nor the last) to whom it happens ;-) nothing to be embarrassed IMHO.

Comment: Happened to me too, very helpful thank you!